# Creating a "File Transfer"-activity - Keeps loading?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, automation, ftp

I am trying to create an automation in SFMC and am currently stuck trying to make a new "File Transfer"-activity. All other activities are working fine.

[image]

- I have tried using different browsers, incognito mode, log out/login, etc.

Does anyone have other ideas?

Best regards

Comment: Create a Salesforce support case would help

Comment: Have you created any FTP accounts/users on the business unit, where you try to create this File Transfer Activity?

Comment: @DucLe Already done this, however maybe someone in this forum had experienced something similar to this

Comment: @LukasLunow Yes - and I have no problem connecting to the FTP-server using FileZilla.

Comment: I remember having the exact same problem on Chrome. However, It worked without any problem on Firefox..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @RachidMamai - tried different browsers, incognito, and even different computers - still no luck...

Answer (score 0):

I recently resolved same issue by granting "View" permission to the assigned user role @ Email - Admin - External Object Sources - File Location

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, my user had multiple overlapping roles, which caused the freezing issue. To resolve the problem, make sure that your user does not have overlapping roles